# Несколько графических оболочек в linux

Tags: kde, gnome, linux

Возможно ли использование нескольких графических оболочек в одной системе и корректная их работа? Т.е. возможно ли иметь возможность выбора, например, между kde и gnomе, при входе в систему?

Comment: Да, чаще всего просто появляется выпадающий список session при логине.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что именно будете использовать - gnome, kde, xmonad, xfce, awesome - не имеет никакого значения. Вам нужно просто использовать (скорее всего он уже установлен) - менеджер входа (login manager). Наиболее популярные - gdm (от гнома), kdm (от KDE) и slim (очень минималистичный менеджер). Первые два предоставляют возможность выбора с списка мышкой (оно по разному сделано, но в принципе понятно. В gdb, к примеру, нужно нажать на "шестеренку"). В Slim это сделано не очень "очевидно" - нужно нажимать F1 до выбора нужного.

Вполне возможно, что Вы не видите этого окна, так как настроен автоматический вход без ввода пароля. Тут придется найти в настройках и отключить его.

Будут ли это все работать нормально? да, с большой вероятностью, проблем не будет. Раньше были проблемы, с автостартом некоторых приложений. Дело в том, что у gnome и KDE есть свои "спецпапки", куда поместив ярлык программы, можно получить автозапуск этой программы. А вот xfce смотрел в обе и запускал много лишнего.

Также можно будет заметить, что некоторые KDE приложения в gnome/xfce будут в начале запускаться немного медленее (потому что нужно подгрузить окружение KDE).

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно. При инсталляции ставите, например, KDE. Потом менеджером пакетов доставляете Gnome. В SuSE, например, при этом автоматически появляется возможность выбора загружаемой графической оболочки в диалоге ввода логина и пароля. Автовход при этом должен быть, естественно, отключен.

Comment: Если не изменяет память, одновременно стояли KDE и GNOME, при этом автологин работал прекрасно. Вроде как дело было даже в openSUSE. Выбор оболочки происходил при выходе из текущего аккаунта.